# TomTom: how to cancel a job once submitted?

Tags: tomtom

Is there any possibility to delete a TomTom trafficstats API job once it has been submitted? After posting a job and receiving the jobID, I sometimes found a mistake in the POST query. I know how to get the status (https:///traffic/trafficstats/status//?key=
) but is there anyway of asking the server to kill the jobID?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There is no way right now to delete that job.